# Cannot update nlohmann::json document using instantiated json_pointer

Tags: c++, json, nlohmann-json

It is pretty useful accessing **nlohmann::json** nodes with a *json_pointer* path. You could do it inline:

```
  nlohmann::json root;
  root["/foo/bar"_json_pointer] = 42;
  std::cout << root.dump(4) << std::endl;
```

This outputs:

```json
   {
       "foo": {
           "bar": 42
       }
   }
```

But when I use the *json_pointer* class built from the path as variable:

```
  nlohmann::json root;
  std::string path = "/foo/bar";
  root[nlohmann::json_pointer<std::string>(path)] = 42;
  std::cout << root.dump(4) << std::endl;
```

it outputs:

```json
{
    "/foo/bar": 42
}
```

What I'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problem was way to instantiate *json_pointer* class.
I don't know how it compiled, but the right way is much more simpler:

```
  nlohmann::json root;
  std::string path = "/foo/bar";
  nlohmann::json::json_pointer j_ptr(path); // <--- this is the way
  root[j_ptr] = 42;
  std::cout << root.dump(4) << std::endl;
```